# how to specify if a button is in false mode in script

Tags: scripting, game-engine

so i just need to know if and how to do this. example one: (all of this will be in blender game engine)

import bge

def main():

```
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner

right = cont.sensors ["right"]
left = cont.sensors ["left"]
gas = cont.sensors ["gas"]

if gas.negative:
    if left.negative:
        if right.negative:
            own ["rotation"] += 0.1
else:
    own ["rotation"] = 0
```

so i just need to know how to say "if im not pressing w, do this" INSTEAD of doing this "if im pressing w do this" normally you do if w.positive:
     blah blah blah...

please help and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put not in the if.

```
from bge import logic
def main():
    cont = logic.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner

    right = cont.sensors ["right"]
    left = cont.sensors ["left"]
    gas = cont.sensors ["gas"]

    if not gas.positive:
        if not left.positive:
            if not right.positive:
                own ["rotation"] += 0.1
    else:
        own ["rotation"] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to specify if a button is in false mode in script

A button is never in "false mode", a button is a key on your keyboard (unless you mean a virtual button on your screen). A button can be pressed or not pressed.

## Sensor evaluation result.

I guess you mean sensor (or more specific button sensor).

Sensors measure their specific condition at each single logic frame while the game is running. For example the keyboard sensor checks if a specific button is pressed or not.

When the the condition is met they switch their evaluation state to True other wise to False. The evaluation state can be read via [sensor.positive](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.78b/bge.types.SCA_ISensor.html#bge.types.SCA_ISensor.positive).

```
if sensor.positive:
   print("condition met")
else: 
   print("condition not met")
```

To check the "not met" condition you still look at the attribute positive:

```
if not sensor.positive:
   print("condition not met")
```

To translate this into the button sensor, you can safely assume when the keyboard sensor does not measure the key positive will be False.

## Invert

Just in case you mean the invert button at the sensor. You can read it with attribute [sensor.invert](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.78b/bge.types.SCA_ISensor.html#bge.types.SCA_ISensor.invert). This is something a Python controller should never care about (unless it is supposed to reconfigure the sensor which is a really rare use case).